# How to restore backup to new disk

Tags: backup, tar

I have to backup /home/dev/ directory, add new disk, create LVM, mount and restore backup to the new mounted volume.

It should look like this at the end:

```
/dev/mapper/vg00-home--dev   22G  3.6G   18G  17% /home/dev
```

To backup I will use:

```
sudo tar -cpzf mybackup.tar.gz \
--exclude=mybackup.tar.gz\
--exclude=jenkins
--warning=no-file-changed .
```

But where should I store backup when adding disk, LVM and so on?

Secondly, to restore should I just go to new /home/dev/ directory and use:

```
tar xvpfz mybackup.tgz
```

or should I did it in a different way? What are the best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you don't have to back up the directory. Once the partition is present, you can just copy the contents and then you can mount it at `/home/dev`. This will hide what's at that location, so you may want to empty that folder not to clutter your disk with old stuff. (I suggest you **do** back it up anyhow just in case. You can store the backup anywhere you like, as long as you don't choose some weird place indeed.)

If you happen to restore the backup, the easiest way is to go to the target location first.

Comment: Thanks! So I should copy content using for example rsync and at the end mount it?

Comment: @Brzozova Yes. Even the normal `cp` will do. You'll probably want to preserve the permissions, etc, so check the `-p` flag.